# HTTP Proxy with Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, http, http-proxy, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a very special setup in one of our projects which raised a question on if it would be possible to implement an HTTP-Proxy in a Spring Cloud Gateway, so that I can use this Spring Cloud Gatway in various other projects to communicate through it via the "HTTP-Proxy"- Protocol.

Has anyone done something like this and pin-point me into a good direction?

So basically I want:

"Some Application" (a client which is not in our control)

- that wants to talk to "https://service-a.company.com/"
- which can be configured with an http_proxy

to communicate

- through a custom application developed as a Spring Cloud Gateway
- This Spring Cloud Gateway will enrich the requests with certain Headers and Information that is requirde by the "remote servers"

to remote servers (which are not in our control).

Hope my question is clear enough!

All the best,
Sebastian

Comment: We have done something similar but right now have only got things working when the upstream is http . Still trying to figure out what i need to tune for https use case.
For http we just overrode the "AbstractChangeRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory" filter which allows you to mutate the upstream path per request .